# richfaces 4 , Rerender attribute in a4j:commandButton and a4j:ajax is gone

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

During the conversion on of a4j:commandButton and a4j:ajax (from richfaces 3 to richfaces 4) I realize that there is no reRender attribute anymore.

what is the alternative to this attribute for reRendering  through these component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's renamed to [the `render` attribute](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/vdldoc/a4j/ajax.html), in order to comply with the [standard JSF `<f:ajax>` tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html).

#### See also:

- [RichFaces 3.x - 4.x migration guide](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces/docs/3-x-4-x-migration) - [a4j components](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration-ComponentsMigration-A4jComponents) (lists all added/removed attributes!)